# How to make or use a standard Image Viewer for WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, image-viewer

I want to make an app that shows pictures. But I want to be able to zoom in and out with gestures. I fixed this by including a toolkit into my project. But my actual question is, can I use or is there a control that's already created for me to show pictures like the picture library of the WP7 phone itself. I thought there wasn't but the Facebook app has a similar way of showing the pictures. Did Facebook rewrite the whole thing or is there a control somewhere that someone made?

Comment: I'm not aware of any library, toolkit or control vendor who has released an image viewer.

Answer (score 0):

The `SlideView` control in Telerik's [RadControls for Windows Phone](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone.aspx) sounds like what you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried a [MultiScaleImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.multiscaleimage%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) control? It's designed to work with multiple layers, but if you only specify one layer, it might suit what you're trying to do.