# WP7 Photo Viewer Control Available?

Tags: windows-phone-7, pivot, image-viewer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make or use a standard Image Viewer for WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602053/how-to-make-or-use-a-standard-image-viewer-for-wp7)

I'm looking for a control that's very similar to what WP7 has in the camera hub. It would be like a pivot control except for that in the right side of the screen one could see a small portion of the next image.

Before starting to code up my own control I was wondering if anyone was aware of such a control existing and its code shared.

Comment: I've not seen such a thing. :(

Comment: Maybe we should create one and open source it. I would contribute :)

Answer (score 0):

MultitouchBehaviours could be a good starting foundation for such UI Component
look at this
http://www.galasoft.ch/touch/wp7/

Answer (score 0):

The `SlideView` control in Telerik's [RadControls for Windows Phone](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone.aspx) sounds like what you're looking for.